# Could I use "snippet" to imply a review on a topic?

Tags: word-usage

Suppose

> In this section, we firstly provide a short snippet on the history of online English learning platforms.

I am wondering if that is a correct usage or perhaps common usage for this word?

If not, what could I use except for "background", "history", and "introduction". I don't want to use them since I have used them a lot and I want to toss in some other words to make my writing a bit less tasteless!

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of other near synonyms of ***snippet*** that you could use - including *a short piece, a short excerpt, a smidgeon, a brief summary* etc.

However if you do use *snippet* you really do not need the adjective *short*, since "snippet" implies brevity. So a "short snippet" is a bit like talking about "a large giant", "wet rain", or a "hot furnace".

Answer (score 0):

Snippet could work, but you could also use "blurb" or "section".

Comment: Welcome to English Language Learners! While this may be correct, we like our answers to be backed up by references. You can [edit] your answer to include one (e.g. an online dictionary). See the Help Center article [answer].